# Docker containers on Windows reporting no space left on device

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have 3 different containers (transmission, qbittorrent and adguardhome), all of them reporting no space left (eg: after downloading ~300mb or when writing a querylog file)

I have more than 300gb left on my desktop, but it seems all the containers are writing somewhere inside, but nothing is visible from my PC file explorer, when navigating to the binds.

I have similar configurations on all docker compose files:

```
services:
  torrent:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/transmission:latest
    container_name: torrent
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Etc/UTC
    volumes:
      - C:\Work\Docker\Torrent\config:/config
      - C:\Users\tavy1\Downloads:/downloads
      - C:\Work\Docker\Torrent\watch:/watch
    restart: unless-stopped
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
      - 9091:9091
      - 51413:51413
      - 51413:51413/udp
    labels:
      # some traefik related configurations
```

In qbitttorrent I can even see that the available space is ~300mb, but I don't know why. Is it a mounting issue? A limitation between partition types?

ps: I am new to docker, it's my first playground setup

Other mentions:

1. I'm using Hyper-V backend, not WSL2  (I guess it shouldn't matter)
2. In Docker desktop settings, I have a SWAP of 4GB and Vdisk limit to 200gb. Also, I am able to see in file sharing all the mounts that are used in my docker compose files.

Comment: What exactly is the error message? Docker itself limits how much disk space it will use; perhaps you need to increase its quota, or free up some space from unused images.

Comment: It's important to always provide the exact error message, rather than your interpretation of it.

Comment: I ran an windows update. Now it's working and I cannot reproduce the issue. Qbittorent shows now "Free space: 371.87 GiB" instead of ~300mb. I think it was something related to the WSL, a bug that has been fixed with the update